# Block diagonalize rows of a J-by-2 matrix

Tags: matlab

Given a `J`-by-2 matrix, for example

```
A = [1 2 ; 3 4 ; 5 6]
```

I want to block diagonalize it. That is, I want:

```
B = [1 2 0 0 0 0 ; 0 0 3 4 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0 5 6].
```

One command that does this is:

```
blkdiag(A(1,:),A(2,:),A(3,:))
```

This is will be slow and tedious if `J` is large. Is there a built-in Matlab function that does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one *hacky* solution for `J x 2` array case using [`linear indexing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) -

```
%// Get number of rows
N = size(A,1);                   

%// Get linear indices of the first column elements positions in output array
idx = 1:2*N+1:(N-1)*(2*N+1)+1;   

%// Setup output array
out = zeros(N,N*2);

%// Put first and second column elements into idx and idx+N positions
out([idx(:) idx(:)+N]) = A
```

There is just one function call (neglecting `size` as it must be minimal) overhead of `zeros` and even that can be removed with [`this undocumented zeros initialization trick`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance) -

```
out(N,N*2) = 0; %// Instead of out = zeros(N,N*2);
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
out =
     1     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     3     4     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     5     6     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     7     8
```

---

Here's a benchmarking for the posted solutions thus far.

**Benchmarking Code**

```
%//Set up some random data
J = 7000;   A = rand(J,2);
%// Warm up tic/toc
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end   
disp('---------------------------------- With @mikkola solution')
tic
temp = mat2cell(A, ones(J,1), 2);
B = blkdiag(temp{:});
toc, clear B temp
disp('---------------------------------- With @Jeff Irwin solution')
tic
m = size(A, 1);
n = size(A, 2);
B = zeros(m, m * n);
for k = 1: n
    B(:, k: n: m * n) = diag(A(:, k));
end
toc, clear B k m n
disp('---------------------------------- With Hacky1 solution')
tic
N = size(A,1);                   
idx = 1:2*N+1:(N-1)*(2*N+1)+1;   
out = zeros(N,N*2);
out([idx(:) idx(:)+N]) = A;
toc, clear out idx N
disp('---------------------------------- With Hacky2 solution')
tic
N = size(A,1);                   
idx = 1:2*N+1:(N-1)*(2*N+1)+1;
out(N,N*2) = 0;
out([idx(:) idx(:)+N]) = A;
toc, clear out idx N
```

**Runtimes**

```
---------------------------------- With @mikkola solution
Elapsed time is 0.546584 seconds.
---------------------------------- With @Jeff Irwin solution
Elapsed time is 1.330666 seconds.
---------------------------------- With Hacky1 solution
Elapsed time is 0.455735 seconds.
---------------------------------- With Hacky2 solution
Elapsed time is 0.364227 seconds.
```

Comment: Indexing without any function call overhead is clearly faster FTW. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Undocumented MATLAB FTW! ;)

Comment: Thanks.  It might make sense to set `out = sparse(N,2*N)` instead of `out(N,N*2) = 0` to avoid a lot of overhead when `N` is large.

Comment: @MattT I haven't dealt with sparse much, so I am not sure. But, if that works, sure!

Comment: @MattT Assigning to `sparse` matrices is **very** costly.  It's better if you actually initialize the `sparse` matrix with non-zero content instead of creating an empty `sparse` matrix and assigning values.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one using [`mat2cell`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to reshape into an J-by-1 cell array where each element contains a row of `A`. Then use the `{:}` operator to push the contents to `blkdiag` as a comma-separated variable list:

```
%//Set up some random data
J = 100;
A = rand(J,2);
%// Solution for arbitrary J-by-2 A
temp = mat2cell(A, ones(J,1), 2);
B = blkdiag(temp{:})
```

---

Nice solutions! I had a few timing results here, but repeated them running the benchmarking code by @Divakar. Results on my end below.

```
---------------------------------- With @mikkola solution
Elapsed time is 0.100674 seconds.
---------------------------------- With @Jeff Irwin solution
Elapsed time is 0.283275 seconds.
---------------------------------- With @Divakar Hacky1 solution
Elapsed time is 0.079194 seconds.
---------------------------------- With @Divakar Hacky2 solution
Elapsed time is 0.051629 seconds.
```

Comment: Not sure about the benchmarking code you have used, but I have added mine, just in case people want to check back. The results are different at my end.

Comment: @Divakar I Repeated the benchmarks running your code instead. Ordering the same as at your end.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution.  Not sure how efficient it is, but it works for a matrix `A` of any size.

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
m = size(A, 1)
n = size(A, 2)

B = zeros(m, m * n)
for k = 1: n
    B(:, k: n: m * n) = diag(A(:, k))
end
```

Comment: The nested call to `diag` would kill your performance, but this is one of the most canonical ways to solve this problem. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this using `sparse` that beats the other solutions both in memory and clock time:

```
N = size(A,1);
ind_1 = [1:N].';
ind_2 = [1:2:2*N-1].';
A_1   = sparse(ind_1,ind_2,A(:,1),N,2*N);
ind_2 = [2:2:2*N].';
A_2   = sparse(ind_1,ind_2,A(:,2),N,2*N);
out       = A_1 + A_2;
```

Results are reported below using the same benchmarking code as @Divakar:

```
---------------------------------- With @mikkola solution
Elapsed time is 0.065136 seconds.
---------------------------------- With @Jeff Irwin solution
Elapsed time is 0.500264 seconds.
---------------------------------- With Hacky1 solution
Elapsed time is 0.200303 seconds.
---------------------------------- With Hacky2 solution
Elapsed time is 0.011991 seconds.
---------------------------------- With @Matt T solution
Elapsed time is 0.000712 seconds.
```